# How to use Xpath Transform

Tags: java, xml, xades4j, xml-dsig

I'm trying to sign a UBL2.1 with xades4j but I need to exclude some tags from being singed.
I used XPathTransform but the resulted digest is not valid.

[image]

Here is the UBL document (not complete document for simplicity) that I'm trying to sign

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <ext:UBLExtensions>
      <ext:UBLExtension>
         <ext:ExtensionContent>
            <sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2" xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2">
               <sac:SignatureInformation>
                  <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</cbc:ID>
                  <sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
               </sac:SignatureInformation>
            </sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
         </ext:ExtensionContent>
      </ext:UBLExtension>
   </ext:UBLExtensions>
   <cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
   <cbc:ID>20210000011041000001</cbc:ID>
   <cbc:UUID>7c0925c8-5536-4b73-aeca-e833f3f78b3c</cbc:UUID>
   <cbc:IssueDate>2021-03-14</cbc:IssueDate>
   <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name="01000">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
   <cbc:Note>Some Notes</cbc:Note>
   <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>USD</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
   <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>USD</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
   <cac:OrderReference />
   <cac:BillingReference>
      <cac:InvoiceDocumentReference />
   </cac:BillingReference>
   <cac:ContractDocumentReference />
   <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
      <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:UUID>20210000011041000001</cbc:UUID>
   </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
   <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
      <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
      <cac:Attachment>
         <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">X+zrZv/IbzjZUnhsbWlsecLbwjndTpG0ZynXOif7V+k=</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
      </cac:Attachment>
   </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
   <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
      <cbc:ID>QR</cbc:ID>
      <cac:Attachment>
         <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">AUrYp9mE2LTYsdmD2Kkg2KfZhNi52LHYqNmK2Kkg2KfZhNmK2YXZhtmK2Kkg2YTZhNin2LPZhdmG2Kog2KfZhNmF2K3Yr9mI2K/YqQIJMTAwMzMxMDMzAxMyMDIxLTAzLTE0MDA6MDA6MDBaBAY0MjU0MDAFATAGQDIyMjk5YjQ0MTU2MDQ0MjYyMzU0YjkzZThhZjNjZThlMjFkNjRjNWVkZWYyZTkxMjk3OTMzNjllM2Y1YmE1MWEHBUVDRHNhWpWNMRzpzfaMmZhfH4APF155H+Fp5LU9xW0umMbEoS47hWKjcYlakCn6Xhx7Ok6iDSN4syJQVaWfAwmARtM1nw==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
      </cac:Attachment>
   </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
   <cac:Signature>
      <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
   </cac:Signature>
</Invoice>
```

I want to exclude these elements from the signature:

```
//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions
//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature
//ancestor-or-self::cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:ID='QR']
```

so, I used the following xpath transform

```
DataObjectDesc obj = new DataObjectReference("")
                .withTransform(new XPathTransform("not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)"))
                .withTransform(new XPathTransform("not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature)"))
                .withTransform(new XPathTransform("not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:ID='QR'])"))
                .withDataObjectFormat(new DataObjectFormatProperty("text/xml"));
```

However the resulted digest is not valid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't check the XPath expressions, but the code seems correct from the xades4j usage PoV. You can also try the XPath 2 transform: http://luisgoncalves.github.io/xades4j/javadocs/1.6.0/reference/xades4j/algorithms/XPath2FilterTransform.html

Comment: I tried XPath 2 Transform 
{.withTransform(XPath2FilterTransform.XPath2Filter.subtract("//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions"))}
but I got the same result

Comment: This was handled in https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/236